# create two columns based on a function with apply()

Tags: python, pandas, list, function, tuples

I have a dataset containing football data of the premier league as such:

```
    HomeTeam    AwayTeam         FTHG  FTAG
0   Liverpool   Norwich            4    1
1   West Ham    Man City           0    5
2   Bournemouth Sheffield United   1    1
3   Burnley     Southampton        3    0
... ...         ...               ...  ...
```

where "FTHG" and "FTAG" are full-time home team goals and away team goals.
I need to write a function that calculates the final Premier League table given the results (in the form of a data frame). What I wrote is this function:

```
def calcScore(row):
    if PL_df.iloc[row]['FTHG'] > PL_df.iloc[row]['FTAG']: 
        x = 3
        y = 0
    elif PL_df.iloc[row]['FTHG'] < PL_df.iloc[row]['FTAG']:
        x = 0
        y = 3
    elif PL_df.iloc[row]['FTHG'] == PL_df.iloc[row]['FTAG']:
        x = 1
        y = 1
    return x,y
```

this works, for example for the first row it gives this output:

```
in[1]: calcScore(0)
out[1]: (3,0)
```

now I need to create two columns HP and AP that contain the number of points awarded for Home and Away teams respectively using apply(). But I can't think of a way to do that.

I hope I was clear enough. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a function (and also faster than `apply`):

```
win_or_draws = df['FTHG'] > df['FTAG'], df['FTHG'] == df['FTAG']

df['HP'] = np.select( win_or_draws, (3,1), 0)
df['AP'] = np.select(win_or_draws, (0,1),3)
```

Output:

```
      HomeTeam          AwayTeam  FTHG  FTAG  HP  AP
0    Liverpool           Norwich     4     1   3   0
1     West Ham          Man City     0     5   0   3
2  Bournemouth  Sheffield United     1     1   1   1
3      Burnley       Southampton     3     0   3   0
```